# Mass of the push forward of a k-current with fixed orientation

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, differential-forms, tensor-calculus

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Mass}{Mass}$Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smoth map. Given a $2$-vector (in general a $k$-vector but let's stick to $2$) $v_1 \wedge v_2  \in \Lambda_2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ you can consider the push forward of such vector through $f$, defined as

$$ \langle f_\# (v_1 \wedge v_2 ) , \omega \rangle =\langle  v_1 \wedge v_2  , f^\#\omega \rangle$$

where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the duality pairing and $\omega $ is a $2$-form. Now, for simplicity assume that $v_1 ,v_2 = e_1 , e_2$, elements of the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $T$ be a $2$-current defined such that its direction is, at every point, $e_1 \wedge e_2$. I can define its push forward just like before, and its mass will be

$$ \sup_{\|\omega\|^* \leq 1}  \langle T, f^\# \omega \rangle $$

where $\|\omega \|^*$ denotes the comass norm. The question is: how does the particular structure of $T$ (i.e. the fact that it is always directed as $e_1 \wedge e_2 $) give me a better mass estimate? What can easily be seen is

$$ \Mass [ (f_\#) T] \leq \|d f\|_\infty ^2 \Mass (T),$$

but for example if $T$ were a $1$-current always in the $e_1$ direction, then it's easy to see that the estimate above can be improved with

$$ \Mass [ (f_\#) T] \leq \|\partial_1 f\|_\infty \Mass (T).$$

Now, maybe this is trivial if one is well-versed in tensor calculus (which I am not), but pulling back a $2$-form (or a $k$-form) totally messes me up, I don't know how to derive a similar estimate, or if there's even one. In case of rectiafiable currents you can improve the estimate by considering the tangential differential, is this true even in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that $T$ has direction $e^1 \wedge e^2$ means that for some distribution $u$, $T = u e^1 \wedge e^2$ (actually, since $T$ has finite mass, $u$ is a Radon measure). We're trying to compute
$$\langle f_\# (u e^1 \wedge e^2), \omega\rangle = \langle u e^1 \wedge e^2, f^\# \omega\rangle = u \langle e^1 \wedge e^2, f^\# \omega\rangle.$$
The pullback is given by
$$\langle e^1 \wedge e^2, f^\# \omega\rangle = \sum_{i < j} f^\# (\langle e^i \wedge e^j, \omega\rangle) \langle e^1 \wedge e^2, df_i \wedge df_j\rangle$$
where $df_i$ is the differential of $f_i$. Now $e^i \wedge e^j$ is a $2$-blade, so by the definition of the comass and the fact that $\omega$ has comass $\leq 1$,
$$|f^\#(\langle e^i \wedge e^j, \omega\rangle)| \leq 1.$$
Meanwhile
$$\langle e^1 \wedge e^2, df_i \wedge df_j \rangle = \partial_1 f_i \partial_2 f_j.$$
In particular $\langle e^1 \wedge e^2, f^\# \omega\rangle$ is a weighted sum, with weights in $[-1, 1]$, of the components of $\partial_1 f \otimes \partial_2 f$ and we conclude that
$$\langle e^1 \wedge e^2, f^\# \omega\rangle \leq C \|\partial_1 f \otimes \partial_2 f\|_{L^\infty} \leq C \|\partial_1 f\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial_2 f\|_{L^\infty}$$
where $C$ is the number of pairs $(i, j) \in \{1, \dots, n\}^2$ with $i < j$. You might be able to improve this $C$.

Anyways we have
$$\langle f_\# T, \omega \rangle \leq C\|\partial_1 f\|_{L^\infty} \|\partial_2 f\|_{L^\infty} \|u\|$$
where the norm of $u$ is its total measure, hence $\|u\|$ is the total mass of $T$.

Comment: Yeah, yesterday after asking I came up with this, but I'd like something slightly better. Correct me if I am wrong, shouldn't you also have that if, say, $T= u(x) e_1 \wedge e_2$, the mass of the push forward is estimated with the integral $\int |\partial_1 f| \; |\partial_2 f| \; |u|$? So that you can use Holder or something like that